# ¿cómo envío el resultado de una consulta echa con php, por correo?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

estoy haciendo una consulta con php a mysql, y la consulta funciona bien, lo que quiero hacer es el resultado de la consulta lo pueda yo mandar por email, el codigo de la consulta es el siguiente:

```
$sentencia = $pdo->prepare(" SELECT * FROM detalleventa,vancas WHERE 
detalleventa.idproducto=vancas.id AND detalleventa.idventa=:ID");
$sentencia->bindParam(":ID", $claveVenta);
$sentencia->execute();
$listaProductos = $sentencia->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

y el código que tengo para enviar el correo es este:

```
$destino="correo@gmail.com";
$nombre="usuario";
$telefono="1234567890";
$asunto="sin asunto";
$mensaje="";
$contenido="Nombre: ".$nombre. "\nCorreo: " .$correo. "\nTelefono: " 
.$telefono."\nMensaje: " .$mensaje;
mail($destino,$asunto,$contenido);
```

el arreglo que me retorna la consulta y que quiero enviar es este:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 175 [idventa] => 22 [idproducto] => 8 
[preciounitario] => 8991 [cantidad] => 1 [vendido] => 0 [modelo] => RP- 
8000NG [colores] => Negro ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 176 [idventa] => 22 
[idproducto] => 8 [preciounitario] => 3020 [cantidad] => 3 [vendido] => 0 
[modelo] => RS-50045 [colores] => Granada ) )
```

en este caso son solo dos posisciones las que tiene el arreglo con multiples valores, pero puede que tenga mas, ¿cómo le hago para que me envíe por correo cada posicion del arreglo separada dentro de un mismo correo?

algo asi por ejemplo:

idventa=22, id prodcto=8, precio unitario=8991,  cantidad=1, vendido=0, modelo=RP-8000NG, colores=negro.

idventa=22, id prodcto=8, precio unitario=8991,  cantidad=1, vendido=0, modelo=RP-8000NG, colores=negro. 
y asi para todas las posiciones del arreglo.
Gracias por su ayuda y comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente teniendo en cuenta que debes moldear con HTML el correo para que te envìe el resultado como lo requieres.

```
$arr = []; // Este es tu array de respuesta

$destino="correo@gmail.com";
$nombre="usuario";
$telefono="1234567890";
$asunto="sin asunto";
$mensaje="";
$contenido="Nombre: ".$nombre. "\nCorreo: " .$correo. "\nTelefono: " 
.$telefono."\nMensaje: " .$mensaje;

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
   $mensaje .= 'id='.$value[id].'<br>';
   $mensaje .= 'idventa='.$value[idventa].'<br>';
   $mensaje .= 'idproducto='.$value[idproducto].'<br>';
   $mensaje .= 'precio unitario?'.$value[preciounitario].'<br>';
   $mensaje .= 'cantidad='.$value[cantidad].'<br>';
   $mensaje .= 'vendido='.$value[vendido].'<br>';
   $mensaje .= 'modelo='.$value[modelo].'<br>';
   $mensaje .= 'colores='.$value[colores].'<br>';
}

mail($destino,$asunto,$contenido);
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo, muy buena tu respuesta

Comment: eres todo un genio jeje

Comment: jajaja por nada, solo revisa las formas de concatenar valores en una variable, es muy útil.